# Kafka : Error from SyncGroup, The request timed out

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Recently we are experiencing "Error from SyncGroup: The request timed out" frequently with the Java Kafka APIs.

This issue usually happens with few topic or consumer group in Kafka cluster. Does anyone can provide some pointers about this error?
As a workaround, if I change the consumer group name I don't see the error.
Broker Version : 0.9.0
Kafka client version : 0.9.0.1

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error from SyncGroup: The request timed out.

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupRequestHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:444)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupRequestHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:411)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:665)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:644)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:380)

at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:274)
```

Comment: What is the Kafka version you are using?

Comment: It's 0.9.0.1 Kafka client APIs

Comment: Are you able to ping the server node from client node? Also is the Kafka server 0.9.0 ?

Comment: Yes, the existing consumers are working fine. The broker version is also 0.9.0

Answer (score 5):

@zer0Id0l

We have had the same problem recently. It happens because some Kafka Streams messages have meta information footprint which is more than a regular one (when you don't use Kafka Streams). To fix the issue, go to **__consumer_offsets** topic settings and set **max.message.bytes** param higher than it is by default. For example, in our case we have **max.message.bytes = 20971520**. That will completely solve your problem.